# How to use AWS Codecommit repo as npm dependency

Tags: npm, aws-codecommit

this is my buildspec file:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  git-credential-helper: yes
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

and in package.json I added:-

```
dependencies : {
"sharedLib":"git+https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/sharedLib#branchname"
}
```

I am getting build error in npm install. Any help will be appritiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through IAM services give a Code commit access to the Role which is assigned to code build.

Then Code build should Run.

Comment: Oh I was missing this thing. Thanks a lot ;  It's working for me now.

Comment: Glad it helped.